# Bizarre PHP output

Tags: php

Can someone explain to me why this code

```
$ar = [
  'item' => '−2',
];

for ($i = 1; $i >= -2; $i--) {
  foreach ($ar as $x => $y) {
    if ($y == $i) {
      echo $y . ' == ' . $i . "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Produces

```
−2 == 0
```

Comment: You sure that's your output? I just ran that exact same script and i get -2 == -2. I copy pasted this code.

Comment: @MarioSegura yes I'm sure. What PHP version are you using?

Comment: @MarioSegura nevermind. It turned out that the minus sign on my end was a special UTF8 character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "−" in your array value is actually Unicode Character 'MINUS SIGN' (U+2212), which PHP doesn't consider as belonging in a numeric string.  (It only recognizes U+002D, the HYPHEN-MINUS, partly because it doesn't support UTF-8 at that level; to a stock PHP, all strings are *byte* strings.)  Since it's not numeric, and the string doesn't even *start* with numeric data, its numeric value is 0.

If you delete the Unicode dash and type in a dash instead (which should enter the ASCII one), the script should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting that result because `-2` is a string - PHP is not performing a numerical comparison. Change `==` to `===` to use strict comparison, which will only return `true` if the values **and their types** are equivalent.

Comment: +1 for your answer, but still can't know why `-2 == 0` and not `-2 == 1`

Comment: @mansoulx have a look at this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton: Take another look at those tables you linked, though.  `"-1"` and `-1` compare equal when you use `==`.

Answer (score 0):

After some researches, i understand know how it works. First, read this from the [doc](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

`The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).`

So `'-2'` is considered as `0` because of `-` (initial portion), so the if statement will be entered only when `i == 0` meaning `-2 == 0`. And then echo `$y - $i`.